# How to use sed for string replacement in Groovy script for Jenkins

Tags: groovy, sed

I am new to Groovy/Jenkins and am trying to get sed to replace "${bamboo}" with the value of {VERSION}. "${bamboo}" is the string in the file that needs to be replaced by a {VERSION} which has a value. This is what I have and it's not working. Any help would be appreciated.

node {

```
    stage ("Git Checkout"){

    ...
    ....
    }


    stage('MVN Package') { 
        pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
        VERSION = pom.version
        sh "echo ${VERSION}"
        def mvnHome = tool name: 'maven-3', type: 'maven'
        def mvnCMD = "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn"
        sh "${mvnCMD} clean package"
        dir("/somepath/"){
            sh """sed -i -e 's/\${bamboo}/${VERSION}/g' /fileName"

        }
}
```

}

bamboo is not a variable in Jenkins but VERSION is, and I need to search for string "${bamboo}" and replace it with the value of $VERSION (which I get from pom.version). Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: single quotes and variables within `sed` does not go very well with each other. try using double-quotes.

Comment: double quotes didn't help. Same issue.. somehow it's looking for a value for {bamboo}.

Comment: Use double escape characters `sh "sed -i -e 's/\\${bamboo}/${VERSION}/g' /fileName"`.

Comment: I had to use `E` rather than `e` in Jenkins shell.

`sh "sed -i -E 's/\\${bamboo}/${VERSION}/g' /fileName"`